# Updating dkms in virtual box complains about secure boot

Tags: boot, virtualbox, uefi

while updating dkms I see this message:

```
Your system has UEFI Secure Boot enabled.                        
UEFI Secure Boot is not compatible with the use of third-party drivers.     
The system will assist you in toggling UEFI Secure Boot. To ensure that 
this change is being made by you as an authorized user, and not by an       
attacker, you must choose a password now and then use the same password     
after reboot to confirm the change.                                         
If you choose to proceed but do not confirm the password upon reboot,       
Ubuntu will still be able to boot on your system but the Secure Boot        
state will not be changed.
```

Comment: It appears the _secure boot_ is on and needs to be switched off.

Comment: how to switch of it